# What would be the most efficient way to find if a number n contains a specific number k?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

Assuming my constraints are
1<=n<=10^9
0<=k<=9

What would be the best algorithm to search this in minimum time?

I have tried 2 methods for this:
My first method
n is the number and k is 4 or 7

```
while(n>0)
 {
         d=n%10;
         if(d==4 || d==7)
         return true;
         n/=10;
 }
```

My second method im converting the number to a string and using the find function:

```
string str = NumberToString(i);
if ((str.find("4") != std::string::npos) || (str.find("7") != std::string::npos))
 c++;
```

Is there another faster way to achieve this?
All i need is that the number should contain 4 or 7

Comment: This looks like a homework question to me, you're more likely to get a positive response from a question like this if you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean by contains? That one of the digits is `k`?

Comment: When you say "contains," do you mean "has k as one of its digits"?

Comment: What do you mean for a number to "contain" another number? Do you mean that `n` represented as a decimal string contains a substring which is `k` represented as a decimal string? In what form do you already have `n` and `k`?

Comment: Anyway, [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) are probably what you want to look at.

Comment: This is not a homework question

Comment: Yes i mean to check if n has the digit k in it

Comment: Why has my question been voted down? I don't understand..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If finding a count of how many times a specific digit appears in a number is what you mean, than the complexity will be **O(n)** where **n** is the length of the string (number):

```
char x = '7';
std::string number("9876541231654810654984431");
int count = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < number.size(); ++i)
    if (number[i] == x) count++;
```

Comment: Should probably be `std::string::size_type i` if you're being *reaally*  picky.

Comment: @BoBTFish: Should it? Can you point out a case where choosing `size_t` over `std::string::size_type` might cause any problem?